# Merge two dictionaries conditionally using dict comprehension

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I'd like two join two dictionaries based on the value of d1 and a substring of the key of d2. The resulting dictionary has the key of d1 with the corresponding value of d2.

```
d1 = {'web02': '23', 'web01': '50'}
d2 = {'server/dc-50': 's01.local', 'server/dc-23': 's02.local'}
```

Would result in = `{web01:s01.local, web02:s02.local}`

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're aiming for here.  How are these two dicts related? You wrote "a substring of the key of d2" except the keys of `d2` don't seem to be relevant.  Did you mean "value"?  And what makes you think you need to use a dict comprehension?

Comment: @ArkistarvhKltzuonstev
They are, corrected that

Comment: `{k: d2['server/dc-{}'.format(v)] for k, v in d1.items()}`?

Comment: @Iguananaut
The key of d2 is contained in the value of d1

Comment: "The key of d2 is contained in the value of d1 "  It looks like the other way around to me, sort of.  But based on what relationship?  That they both contain the sub-string '01'?  By what criterion are you associating keys from one dict with value of the other dict?  Just that they have *any* non-empty substring in common, or what?  It might help to explain more about what you need to do and why,.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is what you need :

```
result = {k1:v2 for k1,v1 in d1.items() for k2,v2 in d2.items() if v1 in k2}
```

**Output** :

```
{'web02': 's02.local', 'web01': 's01.local'}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is done without a nested loop by getting the value using string formatting:

```
data = {k: d2['server/dc-' + v] for k, v in d1.items()}
```

Prints:

```
{'web02': 's02.local', 'web01': 's01.local'}
```